# Creating a table row with different colored glyphicons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to programming, and am trying to create a "client list" example row for a table that has the "client" on the left hand side of the row, and "edit" and "delete" icons to the far right of the same row at a 960 width. I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 and am going to be propagating the list later with jquery. I can't figure out how to get the icons colored (or what the css is supposed to look like for the html).  Here's what html I have so far:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>table</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/global.css">    
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<meta name="description" content="">

</head>


    <body>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hadley, Bump </td>
      <td>
        <i class="pull-right icon-trash"></i>
        <i class="pull-right icon-pencil"></i>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
 </html>
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this you your HEAD (you should eventually make this an external stylesheet, loaded after the others):

```
<style>
.icon-trash {
     color:#ff0000; <-- any hex colour code.
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now something else seems to be happening -- the icons are no longer displaying on the right side? (they actually weren't there before I put that in the head, so not saying it was a result of your solution).  Does anything appear wrong that would be causing this?

Comment: Your code looks fine. It might be an issue in on of your stylesheets.